# Test for significant difference of adjusted means after multiple linear regression

Tags: r, testing, linear-regression, mean, emmeans

I would like to do a mean comparison in the follow-up of my multiple linear regression to investigate if significant differences occur between 2 groups.
For this purpose, I have first built my model:

```
corona_soz <- lm(LZ~age  + belastet_SZ + belastet_SNZ + SES_3 + sex, data = MF)
```

For this model, I would now like to perform a mean comparison for the group sex.
Sex has 2 characteristics, namely:
1 == male (german: männlich)
2 == female (german: weiblich)
I have additionally calculated the adjusted means with the emmeans formula:

```
emmeans(mean_MF, ~ sex)
```

The Output:

```
> emmeans(mean_MF, ~ sex)
sex emmean     SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
   1   7.05 0.0193 20894     7.02     7.09
   2   6.96 0.0187 20894     6.93     7.00
```

Now, how can I compare the adjusted means of the two groups (sex==1 (male) and sex ==2 (female)) to see if a significant difference occurs between these two groups?
Is there a formula here that I can plug the model into?
or even better, a formula in which I can directly insert the adjusted means to compare them with each other for significance (p-value)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
EMM <- emmeans(mean_MF, ~ sex)
contrast(EMM, "pairwise")
```

See, for example, the [Quick-start guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/AQuickStart.html)